# stop the video while close popup window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

while i click on open video button one popup window will display . but after closing that popup window video sound playing contentiously i want to stop that video at the time of closing popup window .

pop_video.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('.push').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'video_pop.html',
                success: function (r) {
                    $('#mymodal').show();
                    $('#details_supp').show().html(r);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var closevideobutton = '.hidevideo';
        $(closevideobutton).click(function () {
            $('#details_supp').find('iframe').attr('src', '');
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" id="" class="push" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Video</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close x" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Evelution Of Investing</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="details_supp" class="modal-body" style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button x" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

video_pop.html

```
<center>
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9B7te184ZpQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: Put everything inside $(function()){}

Comment: i tried this also but not working

Comment: which fiddle you want

Comment: You are defining jquery twice in your code and also move the script at the end of body

Comment: i removed js from code but still it's playing video after closing popup window

Comment: Try `$('#details_supp').find('iframe').remove()` when closing

Comment: no it's also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It looks like a typo :**

`$(closevideobutton)` doesn't point to anything.

You may want to change
`var closevideobutton = '.hidevideo';`
to
`var closevideobutton = '.btn-default, .close';`

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tECn7qp2z2TDg2hCEMGF?p=preview)  *(I removed the ajax because of a problem with plunkr)*

Comment: @plunkr actually i am getting this video from database that way i used ajax .

Comment: :) plunkr is the name of the service I used to show you the working code. You don't have to remove the ajax part from your code; it's only because this service has some limitations, I don't want to dig into right now, that I altered it. The main change is this only line I pointed in my answer.

Comment: @plunkr its working in proper way using ajax you did something wrong .